# Select records with max value of one attribute scoped to the other attribute in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

We have `User` model table:

```
group_id|posts|...
1       |5    |...
1       |20   |...
2       |7    |...
1       |15   |...
3       |10   |...
3       |12   |...
```

And we have `Group` model, which `has_many :users`

I would like to select `Group` with `User` having the highest posts scoped to `group_id`.

It's important to have only one `User` in JOIN, because later I'm building `WhereChain` which filters collection based both on `User` and `Group`.

Thanks

Comment: `User.order(posts: desc).first.group` (one maximum `posts` value scenario)?

Comment: I need collection of `Group`, not only one.

Answer (score 4):

```
 posts = User.group(:group_id).maximum(:posts)
 Group.joins(:users).where(users: {posts: posts.values})
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low quality by the system -- take a look around at other answers being given and you'll see that high quality answers give more context and explanation.  Adding an explanation as to why and how this works would greatly improve it.

Comment: Ah, if `posts` have two same values for two different users, it will find them both.

Comment: posts = User.group(:group_id).maximum(:posts) -> posts have all group_id with maximum user.posts. May be, you can execute groups simple? Group.where(id: posts.keys), or you need users in join?

Comment: Genius! Would be really cool if there were a way to combine into one query.